# How to diagram or breakdown the sentence : "What you think is right is not right"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, diagramming

I'm very confused.
[image]

Is this correct.
And between 'think' and 'is' which one is the main verb?

Thank you

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with the diagram method to answer, but my approach would be to first consider replacing the subject of the sentence with something simpler. That is "what you think is right" could become "Pam's thoughts" (but are instead of is) or "your 'correct' thought". Welcome to ELU, by the way.